# Java Swing setBounds() off by 1 pixel

Tags: java, swing

This isn't so much a question as a request for confirmation that a) I'm not crazy, and b) I'm not doing my math wrong.

If I draw a rectangle (0,0,10,10), the top left is pixel (0,0), the bottom right is (10,10).  That means each line actually occupies 11 pixels in the same way an array with elements 0 - 10 has a length of 11.

setBounds (0,0,10,10) on the other hand, sets the top left pixel to (0,0) and the bottom right pixel to (9,9), which is a true 10 pixel x 10 pixel box.

The practical implication is that you can't draw a 10-wide rectangle inside a 10-wide component, because a 10-wide rectangle is really 11-wide, and the rightmost pixel will be cut-off.  Is that right?

The code below demonstrates the behavior by creating a 460-wide rectangle inside a 460-wide component.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestBox extends JPanel {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame window = new JFrame("TestBox");
    TestBox content = new TestBox();
    window.setContentPane(content);
    window.pack();
    Dimension screensize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    window.setLocation( (screensize.width - window.getWidth())/2,
                        (screensize.height - window.getHeight())/2 );
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    window.setResizable(false);  
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
  private Box box;
  public TestBox(){
    setLayout(null);
    setPreferredSize( new Dimension(500,500) );
    setBackground(new Color(200,200,200));
    box = new Box();
    add(box);
    box.setBounds( 20, 20, 460, 460 );
  }
  private class Box extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent( Graphics g ){
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g.drawRect( 0, 0, 460, 460 );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `g.drawRect(0,0,10,10)` the right-most drawn pixel will be at x=9, so the bottom right drawn pixel is at (9,9), not (10,10). Consider `g.drawRect( 0,0,1,1)`. This will draw a single pixel at coordinates(0,0).

Oops - sorry. I was thinking of g.fillRect(), not g.drawRect(). Yes, you are right, as you can demonstrate if set the background to green, set the panel size to 3,3, then set color to red and g.drawRect(0,0,2,2) you will se a red square with a center green pixel - the bottom right red pixel is at (2,2).

And even more so, g.drawRect(0,0,0,0) will draw a single pixel.